# No WSGI daemon process

Tags: python, flask, centos

I have a Flask project configured in centos 8 Instance.
Arlready installed mod_wsgi .(dnf -y install python3-mod_wsgi)
when we load the project, server log we are getting the below error

No WSGI daemon process called 'ai-newsapi_final' has been configured: /var/www/html/ai-india-grillchatbot/app.wsgi

Comment: virtual host configuration is
 WSGIDaemonProcess ai-india-grillchatbot  user=apache group=apache threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /grill /var/www/html/ai-india-grillchatbot/app.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/ai-india-grillchatbot/>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIProcessGroup ai-newsapi_final
                AllowOverride None
               Require all granted

Comment: please add the additional Information in the question using the `edit` button instead of adding it in a comment.